# Java generics upper bounded wildcard restriction

Tags: java, generics

Can someone explain what's the difference between these two snippets of code ? 
1)

```
private Collection<Animal> getAnimal() {
    return null;
}
```

2)

```
private Collection<? extends Animal> getAnimal() {
    return null;
}
```

I understand that `?` is a wildcard and I can use anything instead of it. Then I specify extends which bound that wildcard to Animal but in that case isn't the first example the same as second ? What's the difference ?
Thanks

Comment: PECS -- [producer extends, consumer super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) Basically, you can take an `Animal` out of the second one, but you can't put any type of object into it.  If that's not the intended use model, then use the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collection<Animal>` is more restrictive than `Collection<? extends Animal>` because `Collection<Animal>` matches only `Animal` type, but `? extends Animal` matches `Animal` or any of its subclasses. Consider below example

**Example** `sum` method will accept `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>` or `List<Number>`

```
public static double sum(List<? extends Number> numberlist) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (Number n : numberlist) sum += n.doubleValue();
  return sum;
 }
```

**Main** Call `sum()` with `List<Integer>` or `List<Double>` will work without any issues

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
  System.out.println("sum = " + sum(integerList));

  List<Double> doubleList = Arrays.asList(1.2, 2.3, 3.5);
  System.out.println("sum = " + sum(doubleList));
 }
```

But the below method will only accept `List<Number>`, now if you try to call passing `List<Integer>` or `List<double>` you will have Compile time error

```
public static double sum(List<Number> numberlist) {
      double sum = 0.0;
      for (Number n : numberlist) sum += n.doubleValue();
      return sum;
   }
```

**CE**

```
The method sum(List<Number>) in the type NewMain is not applicable for the arguments (List<Double>)
The method sum(List<Number>) in the type NewMain is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>)
```